# Regular expression vectors

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to load a file using python (pandas) and regular expressions. I found a workaround to solve my issue but I still would like to find a one line solution, it may be useful for the future. The file format is the following:

```
1   (a b   c)  (a  b c)   (a b c)
2 (a b c) (a b c)    (a b c)
3       a b   c  a  b c   a b c
```

Notice that some are spaces and some are tabs and the number of tab and/or spaces is not constant. The expected result is the following dataFrame:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
1   2   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
2   3   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
```

My best result was obtained using:

```
pd.read_csv('filepath', delimiter='\)*\s+\(*', engine='python', header = None)
```

Which gives:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c)
1   2   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c)
2   3   a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
```

And then i get rid of the ")" with additional processing. I still don't understand why \s+ is enough to remove the tabs i.e. \t (if somebody can answer this question as well, it is definitely a bonus).

I have tried different things but I couldn't find a single regex that does the job. Some of my attempts:

```
\)*\s*\(*
(\)*\s+\(*)|(\))
(\)*\s+\(*)|(\)\n)
```

Some are clear why they do not work, but I expected the last one to be the right solution. Another idea would be to use `\)*\s*\(*` but forcing at least one character to be in the regex, but I did not find if it is possible.

Any idea what would be a better regex?

P.S. If I read the file line by line and I use re.split with regex the splitting looks different, but I would prefer using pandas.

Comment: This results in a final column of `NaN`, which can easily be dropped but still comes up a bit shy

Comment: `\s+` is enough to remove tabs because it translates to "one or more spaces", which will match a tab `\t`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([re.sub(r'[\(\)]', '', line).split()
                      for line in open('data.txt').readlines()])

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
1  2  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
2  3  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'\s*\(|\)\s*\(|\)|\s+'` as delimiter.

- `\s*\(` will match an opening parenthesis preceded by zero or any number of whitespace characters
- `\)\s*\(` will match a closing parenthesis followed by zero or any number of whitespace characters followed by a closing parenthesis
- `\)` will match a closing parenthesis
- `\s+` will match one or more white space character

Make sure to pass engine as `python` to avoid warning for using `regex` as separator, you'll get one `NaN` column in the end which you can just drop:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


csv_data = '''1   (a b   c)  (a  b c)   (a b c)
2 (a b c) (a b c)    (a b c)
3       a b   c  a  b c   a b c'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data),
                delimiter='\s*\(|\)\s*\(|\)|\s+', 
                engine='python', 
                header=None).dropna(axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
1  2  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
2  3  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
```